# Maui binding background to collectionview item bug

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui, .net-maui

I tried binding the background of a border to a LinearGradientBrush in CollectionView and the background changes for other items as well

CommonObject

```
    public partial class CommonObject:ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool showSubmenu = false;


    }
```

Object

```
public partial class Product :CommonObject
{

ResourceDictionary rd = App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.First();

 
        [ObservableProperty]
        string id = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        string name = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        string description = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        string categoryId = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        string barcode = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        decimal salePriceExclVat = 0.00m;
        [ObservableProperty] 
        decimal salePrice = 0.00m;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string saleTaxRateId = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        decimal eatOutPriceExclVat = 0.00m;
        [ObservableProperty]
        decimal eatOutPrice = 0.00m;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string eatOutTaxRateId = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        decimal costPriceExclVat = 0.00m;
        [ObservableProperty]
        decimal costPrice = 0.00m;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string costTaxRateId = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        string brandId = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        string supplierId = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        string popUpInfoId = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        string mainUnitOfMeasureId = "";
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool trackStock = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int posOrder = 0;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isSellOnPos = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isFavorite = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isSellOnSelfService = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isSellOnAllLocations = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isVariablePrice = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isSoldByWeight = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isComposite = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(IsNotSelected))]
        bool isSelected = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(IsSelected))]
        bool isNotSelected = true;
        [ObservableProperty]
        double opacity = 150;
        [ObservableProperty]
        decimal quantity = 0;
        [ObservableProperty]
        Discount discount = null;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool hasDiscount = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool val = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool proc = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        LinearGradientBrush bgColor = new LinearGradientBrush();
        [ObservableProperty]
        Color textColor = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
        [ObservableProperty]
        Color pTextColor = Color.FromRgb(241, 100, 63);
        partial void OnIsSelectedChanged(bool value)
        {
            try
            {
                
                    IsNotSelected = !value;
                    Opacity = value==true ? 0 : 150;
                    if (value)
                    {
                        if (BgColor != (LinearGradientBrush)rd["SelectedItemGradient"])
                            BgColor = rd["SelectedItemGradient"] as LinearGradientBrush;
    
                        if (TextColor != Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255))
                            TextColor = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
    
                        if (PTextColor != Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255))
                            PTextColor = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
                    }
                    if (!value)
                    {
                        if (BgColor != (LinearGradientBrush)rd["NotSelectedItemGradient"])
                            BgColor = rd["NotSelectedItemGradient"] as LinearGradientBrush;
    
                        if (TextColor != Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0))
                            TextColor = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
    
                        if (PTextColor != Color.FromRgb(241, 100, 63))
                            PTextColor = Color.FromRgb(241, 100, 63);
                    }
    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
    
                ;
            }
    
    
        }
    
    
    }
```

and the CustomView for the product

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:ObjectModel="clr-namespace:MicroPos.Models.ObjectModels"
             x:DataType="ObjectModel:Product"
              xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MicroPos.ViewModels"
             xmlns:Converter="clr-namespace:MicroPos.Converters"  
             Margin="0" Padding="0"  BackgroundColor="Transparent"  InputTransparent="False"
             xmlns:xct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        
             x:Class="MicroPos.Views.Custom.ProductView">



    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModel:PosPageViewModel }},Path=AddProductCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>

    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,30" Margin="0,10,15,0" InputTransparent="True" CascadeInputTransparent="True" IsClippedToBounds="False" HeightRequest="115" WidthRequest="106">



        <Border  Background="{Binding BgColor}" Stroke="Transparent" IsVisible="true" StrokeThickness="0" InputTransparent="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                   
                   Margin="0" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModel:PosPageViewModel }},Path=AddProductCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>

            </Border.GestureRecognizers>
            <Border.StrokeShape>
                <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" />
            </Border.StrokeShape>
        </Border>

        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2,5,2,0" Grid.Row="0" InputTransparent="True"
                   TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                   FontSize="15" FontFamily="RobotoMedium" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding SalePrice}" Grid.Row="1" InputTransparent="True"
                   Margin="0,0,0,5" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="18" FontFamily="RobotoMedium" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="{Binding SalePrice}"   FontSize="15" FontFamily="RobotoMedium" TextColor="{Binding PTextColor}"/>
                                <Span Text=" RON"   FontSize="13" FontFamily="RobotoMedium" TextColor="{Binding PTextColor}"/>
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
      
    </Grid>

      <Border BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Main}" InputTransparent="True"
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0" 
                   WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25" 
                    HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,2,0" Padding="0" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}"
                   VerticalOptions="Start"   Grid.Row="0">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="25,25,25,25" />
        </Border.StrokeShape>
        <Label Text="{Binding Quantity}" Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" InputTransparent="True"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="12" FontFamily="RobotoRegular" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
    
    
    

</Grid>
```

CollectionView

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collection" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" ItemTemplate="{Binding ViewType}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" 
                        ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepScrollOffset"  Margin="10,0,0,0" ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem" 
                         Grid.Row="2" ItemsLayout="{Binding Layout}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
```

video with the behavior

https://youtube.com/shorts/JmHHzm2XoI4

Please help me i realy dont know what to do and the collectionview is very laggi

Comment: What if you wrap a border inside the collectionview like <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border>
                    
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate> .If possible, ,could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Answer (score 0):

First.
Use styling with setters and make use of that visual state.

```
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="MyBorderStyle">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="..."/>
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>                           
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="..."/>                            
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Or... Use Triggers.

Second.
I bet you think CollectionView is laggy, because you are in Debug.
If you change to Release, it will speed up in order of magnitude.
Always test performance in Release. You never know how many tracers/loggers  are messing with your program in debug.

Try this, and tell me how it went.